# Manually mark executable as "from another computer" on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, security

When I download software on Windows they get a security flag that I can see by right-clicking it and selecting `Properties`. On the `General` tab there is a section that says "Security: This file came from another computer and might be blocked to help protect this computer.", with a checkbox for unblocking it.

I am a software developer and I want to do some testing with this.

Once I unblock a file the checkbox goes away. How can I manually re-block it?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1342990/how-can-i-make-windows-think-a-file-came-from-another-computer/1343001#1343001

Comment: Ah, dang. My Q&A is a duplicate of that. Too bad it didn't come up before/while I was writing up mine!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I make Windows think a file "came from another computer"?](https://superuser.com/questions/1342990/how-can-i-make-windows-think-a-file-came-from-another-computer)

Comment: Yes. That's the same question that @HelpingHand posted. I have already marked my question as a duplicate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Files are marked as "from another computer" using NTFS Alternate Data Streams, as [James so graciously explained](https://superuser.com/a/590798/1955) in another question. I also found a nice guide called [Introduction to Alternate Data Streams](https://hshrzd.wordpress.com/2016/03/19/introduction-to-ads-alternate-data-streams/).

You can run commands to read and write ADS data from the Command Prompt:

```
MORE < "myapp.exe:Zone.Identifier"

(
ECHO [ZoneTransfer]
ECHO ZoneId=4
)>myapp.exe:Zone.Identifier
```

And from Powershell:

```
Get-Content -Path .\myapp.exe -Stream Zone.Identifier

Set-Content -Path .\myapp.exe -Stream Zone.Identifier -Value "[ZoneTransfer]`nZoneId=4"
```

Some browsers also store other metadata there, such as the Referer and Host URLs of a download.

You can read more about zones at [About URL Security Zones](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/ms537183(v=vs.85)). The default ones are:

```
Value    Setting
------------------------------
0        My Computer
1        Local Intranet Zone
2        Trusted sites Zone
3        Internet Zone
4        Restricted Sites Zone
```

You can read about other known ADS names at [Known Alternate Stream Names](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-fscc/4f3837c4-2f96-40d7-b0bf-80dd1d0b0da0).

Comment: It should be noted that Alternate Data Streams can only be created on NTFS file systems; FAT file systems do not have the provisions to support them.